# Origin of “fiorume” and its semantic relationship with “fiore”

Tags: etymology

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiorume) says that *fiorume* derives form *fiore*, but I am intrigued by the semantic relationship between the two words, namely what sense of *fiore* may have originated *fiorume*. I’ve looked up *fiorume* in two dictionaries:

> fiorume s. m. [der. di *fiore*]. – Tritume che residua dal fieno, composto di semi, fiori, parti di foglie, ecc.
>   [(Treccani)](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiorume)
>
> AGR Tritume di fieno che resta nei fienili
>   [(Dizionario Hoepli Italiano di Aldo Gabrielli)](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/F/fiorume.php)

So I thought maybe it is called *fiorume* because it is to a large extent made up of flowers; but I wouldn’t expect flowers to be a significant part of what’s left of hay in a barn. Or maybe it comes from *fiore* in the sense of ‘best of something’; if *fiorume* contains lots of seeds maybe it could be very nutritious for animals. But I’m uncertain about this too. In my native Portuguese the suffix *-ume* often has a negative connotation, but I don’t known whether that is also the case in Italian.

So that’s what I’d like to know. Why is that stuff called *fiorume*? Because it’s made of flowers? Is the best part of the hay? Some other reason?

Comment: Not an answer: among the dictionaries I have checked, most only give variations on “der. di *fiore*”, while the recent edition of Devoto-Oli gives “ETIMO Der. pegg. di *fiore*” so, yes, apparently the negative connotation of *-ume* is there.

Answer (score 4):

***[Fiorume](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=fiorume):***

> residuo del fieno ammucchiato.
>
> - Etimologia: ← propr. ***pegg. di fiore***.

(Garzanti)

As suggested by the article below, the “negative” connotation that fiorume suggests is probably derived from the fact that it refers to the residual part of hay (hay was considered most valuable because it was used to feed animals which produced milk and meat); but this residual part actually contains important seeds of different species which could be used to improve grass production in the existing fields.

***[Fiorume](http://www.biodiversita.lombardia.it/sito/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102:introduzione&catid=87&showall=&limitstart=2&Itemid=794):***

> - I nostri nonni sapevano che il miscuglio di semi che si deposita sul pavimento dei fienili può essere utilizzato per creare un nuovo prato o per migliorare un prato esistente.
> - Oggi chiamiamo fiorume non solo il residuo che si raccoglie nei fienili, ma anche e soprattutto un miscuglio di semi di elevato pregio naturalistico, intenzionalmente prodotto a partire da un prato naturale o semi naturale mediante trebbiatura diretta del fieno. Se il prato donatore è ricco di specie vegetali, il fiorume ne rispecchierà la biodiversità, e, se tali specie sono pure autoctone, la semente rappresenterà un materiale di alta qualità per inerbimenti e ripristini ambientali.

(www.biodiversita.lombardia)

Riferimenti al fiorume ci sono già all’inizio del '700 come in  [“L'economia del cittadino in villa](https://books.google.it/books?id=qtJQAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA423&dq=%22fiorume%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG7dKlk4fXAhUrDMAKHcRdCg0Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22fiorume%22&f=false)” di Vincenzo Tanara (1713):

> - E perche non resti il primo anno affatto infruttuoso, se li può poner faue, col sopra seminarsi Trifoglio, ò fiorume di fenile, & a questo modo haurai l'vtile della faua, senza dimagrare il terreno, come succederia se ci seminasti rape, ò miglio, come consegliano alcuni, riportandone ancor qualch'vtile dall'herba del Trifoglio, ...

Comment: Piccola nota: quelle strane f senza il taglio sono in realtà una grafia arcaica per le s...

Comment: Hai ragione, @DenisNardin, sono anche il simbolo dell'integrale (come iniziale di "somma").

Comment: Forse qualche frase dovrebbe essere tradotta in inglese?

Comment: @Charo - I made an English introduction explaining the content  of the article (hope it is clear) the rest is a dictionary entry and usage evidence from and old text. I think that asking a question on an Italian language site may imply a reasonable effort from the OP to understand Italian,  at least to a basic level. If the  OP  needs more details I’ll be happy to help. Btw, asking about the etymology of “fiorume” is not for beginners.